# Probablity: Is my way of thinking correct?

Tags: probability

## Problem

Consider the model such as:

- The computer has not infected with any virus in the initial state.
- Every morning, the computer has infected with an new virus with a probability of $p$ ($0 < p < 1$).
- Every evening, if the computer has infected, the antivirus software tries to remove all viruses. However, it fails with a probability of $q$ ($0 \le q \le 1$).

  1. Let $P(n)$ be the probability that the computer has infected at the end of the $n$-th day. Find $P(1)$, $P(2)$ and $P(n)$.
  2. Find the probability that the computer has *never* infected by the end of the $n$-th day.
  3. Find the probability that the computer has infected at the first day and the software has *never* succeeded in removing by the end of the $n$-th day.
  4. Find the probability that the computer has infected at the $i$-th day ($1\le i \le n$) for the first time and the software has *never* succeeded in removing by the end of the $n$-th day.

## My answer

1. Listing all possibility, $P(1) = pq$, $P(2) = pq(1+q(1-p))$, and $P(n) = P(n-1) \cdot (1+q(1-p)) = pq (1+q(1-p))^n$.
2. Since the computer has not infected every morning, $(1-p)^n$.
3. $p \cdot q^n$.
4. Since the computer has not infected every morning to $(i-1)$-st day, has infected at $i$-th morning, and the software fails to remove from $i$-th evening, $(1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p \cdot q^{n-i+1}$.

Is my way of thinking correct?

Thanks

Comment: I don't fully understand the definition of the problem. Can the computer get infected with more than one virus? Or are its possible states just "infected" and "not infected"?

Comment: The computer can get infect with more than one virus, but I think its possible states are just infected or not, because these problems ask the probability whether the computer get infected or not.

Comment: In 1. $P(2)$ and $P(n)$ are incorrect. The rest seems correct!

Comment: Having rethought $P(n)$, I got $P(n) = \dfrac{pq^2(p-1)\{(1-p)q\}^{n-1}+pq}{1-(1-p)q}$. (Although I rethought $P(2)$ too, the same result as above was got.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

$\begin{align}
P(1)&=pq\\
P(2)&=P(1)q+P(1^C)pq\\
&=pq^2+(1-pq)pq\\
&=pq^2+pq-p^2q^2\\
&=pq(1+q(1-p))\\
P(n)&=P(n-1)q+P((n-1)^C)pq\\
&=^1\frac{pq(q-pq)^n-1}{q-pq-1}
\end{align}$

[$=^1$ Using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28n%29%3Df%28n-1%29q%2B%281-f%28n-1%29%29pq%2C%20f%281%29%3Dpq%2C%20f%282%29%3Dpq%281%2Bq%281-p%29%29)

2.

$(1-p)^n$

3.

$pq^n$

4.

$(1-p)^{i-1}pq^{n-i+1}$

I got the very same results, so I guess that your way of thinking is correct. I know that you might appreciate some explanation, but you already gave it.